# How to send picture or video over bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, pictures, video

I didn't find any way to send taken picture to my friend via bluetooth. Is it even possible on my device - Samsung Omnia 7? Or on other devices?

Comment: This is unforgiveable that this feature is not available on windows phone.
I always thought this phone was aimed at business users/professionals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, transferring files over bluetooth is not possible. This is [requested for](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2536338-please-enable-bluetooth-file-transfer) as a feature for newer releases of the OS.

If you have an unlocked phone, you can use the [DFT BT File Transfer](http://www.wpcentral.com/dft-releases-bluetooth-file-transfer-utility-fully-unlocked-phones-homebrew) utility to send files over bluetooth.

Comment: One more question: does this mean the transfer is not possible either way - from AND to   the phone?

Comment: Yup it means that. I would suggest you use an app like Whatsapp to send files over a data connection since the bluetooth option does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

No you can not send image if you do not have an app (which is only avaliable for DEVELOPER unlocked phones, i believe)

Comment: I was afraid of this answer... Is this true for every device running on Mango? Can you provide link to the app you are mentioning?

Comment: Can you also explain how phones get developer unlocked?